# convert JSON dictionary to NSDictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am using SwiftyJSON to parse JSON. I have the results in an array, here:

```
    func getData() {
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.retrieveJsonInfo { (json: JSON) in
        let results: JSON = json["quotes"]
        print(results)

        for (x, y) in results {

        }

    }
}
```

the print(results) does indeed print the results that I expect it to. The dictionary is of type (String, JSON), but the key value pairs exist as (String: Int) (if that makes any sense). I want to iterate through each key value pair and append the string to an array of strings, and the integer to an array of Ints. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
  for (x, y) in results {
            self.currencyNamesArray.append(x) as! String
            self.numberArray.append(y) as! Int
        }
```

and the first line gave me an error: "cast from () to unrelated type String always fails"

And the second line gives me an error: "can not convert value of type "JSON" to expected value of type "Int"

how can I get the results out of the JSON format and into either a swift dictionary or NSDictionary?

EDIT: the answer is:

```
     for (x, y) in results {
            self.currencyNamesArray.append(x)
            self.numberArray.append(y.intValue)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
```

x is already of type String, so no additional work is needed there. For the int value, I just need to call the .intValue method on it.

Comment: You can get an int or a string from SwiftyJSON objects by using the following functions: .stringValue, .intValue, .boolValue, .doubleValue etc.

Comment: if you post it as an answer I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an int or a string from SwiftyJSON objects by using the following functions: .stringValue, .intValue, .boolValue, .doubleValue etc.